# SQL SERVER: How can I autofill out columns for a table instead of having to type them out?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table with alot of columns and I want to do an ISNULL on one of the columns.  At the moment my select statement is just `SELECT *` though.  Is there a shortcut/way to get the columns to write out in a comma separate list in the select for my table so I don't have to type them all out?

Thanks!

Comment: Highlight your query, go into query designer (Ctrl + Shift + Q). It'll expand * for you (even over multiple tables, it'll fully qualify them for you).

Comment: Don't use the Query Designer. It is horribly buggy.

Comment: When fiddling about it is often convenient to duplicate columns for ease of reading.  Simply `select FooName, FooDate, * from Foos` for quick look at two columns with the rest providing context.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I had noticed - as long it's a simple query it seems to work!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Management Studio Object Explorer expand the table.

Select the "Columns" node and drag that into your query window. It will generate a comma delimited list of all columns in the table.

[image]

Comment: +1 added a screen shot for visualization. It's a view not a table, but same idea.

Comment: @MartinSmith & AaronBertrand, amazing!

Comment: Yeah! Been using management studio for years and didn't know this. Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

in management studio right click on table -> Script table as -> Select to -> Clipboard - > paste into your query window.

or
use plugin tool like Red Gates SQL Prompt which lets you to just key 'ctrl + space' after the * to populate all columns